# Exiting if/else statements in swift

Tags: if-statement, swift

I just started learning Swift and am having some issues. I need to be able to exit an if statement if a condition is met, but have no idea how to do so. For example:

```
if variable1 == 0 { 
// exit if statement, don't do anything 
} 
else { 
// execute this code
```

The VB equivalent for this would be exit sub, though that does not work in swift :(

I have tried searching on Google but have not found anything haha. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: just change it to `if variable1 != 0 { // do this code }`

Comment: The equivalent to `Exit Sub` is `return`, but an `If` statement is not a subroutine.

Comment: Okay awesome!! And if variable1 IS equal to 0 will the code do nothing and move on?

Comment: Or if you might want to do something later in the if statement, use `if variable1 == 0 { } else { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Have you look into the swift guard statement?

**[Guard Statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html)**

A guard statement is used to transfer program control out of a scope if one or more conditions aren’t met.

A guard statement has the following form:

```
guard condition else {
    statements
}
```

The value of any condition in a guard statement must have a type that conforms to the BooleanType protocol. The condition can also be an optional binding declaration, as discussed in Optional Binding.

Any constants or variables assigned a value from an optional binding declaration in a guard statement condition can be used for the rest of the guard statement’s enclosing scope.

The else clause of a guard statement is required, and must either call a function marked with the noreturn attribute or transfer program control outside the guard statement’s enclosing scope using one of the following statements:

- return
- break
- continue
- throw

**example:**

```
        guard let pathToVideo:String = videosRecordedPath as? String else { return }
```